# Removing duplicate rows in html table based on a one column

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, duplicates

```
<table id="test" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>test1<td>
        <td>00.00.00<td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>test2<td>
        <td>00.00.00<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test1<td>
        <td>00.00.01<td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test2<td>
        <td>00.00.01<td>
    </tr> 
</table>


<script type="text/javascript" >
var seen = {};
    $('table tr ').each(function() {
       var txt = $(this).text();
       if (seen[txt]) $(this).remove();
       else seen[txt] = true;
    });
</script>
```

I tried it with the above jquery script but it fails for this scenario. I would like to remove duplicates only based on the first column. any suggestions on this, please?

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = $("#test tr");

$.each(arr, function(i, item) {
    var currIndex = $("#test tr").eq(i);
    var matchText = currIndex.children("td").first().text();
    $(this).nextAll().each(function(i, inItem) {
        if(matchText===$(this).children("td").first().text()) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/HL7p8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var txt = $(this).text();
```

to:

```
var txt = $("td:first-child", $(this)).text();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/p72BB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map()` function to create an array of objects containing the value and the element.  Iterate through this array comparing each value to other values in the array, removing the `tr` elements when duplicates are encountered.

**It should also be noted that the html has several unclosed `td` tags**

**Javascript**

```
var values = $("#test tr td:first").map(function(){
    return {e: this, val: $(this).html()};
});

$.each(values, function(i,e){
    $.each(values,function(ind,el){
        if(el.val == e.val){
           $(el.e).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="test" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>00.00.00</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>00.00.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>00.00.01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>00.00.01</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/p72BB/3/

Comment: You have duplicate `test2` row.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I misunderstood the question

Comment: Your fiddle still isn't working. Change `:first` to `:first-child`. You're only selecting the first TD in the table, not the first TD on each row.